# fopen fails with getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php

I am having problems with the following code:

> ```
> function http_file_exists($url){
> $f=fopen($url,"r");
> if($f){
>     fclose($f);
>     return true;
> } else {
>   return false;
> }
> ```
>
> } 
>   $url = "http://www.minhemmelighed.dk/Graphics/Products/55.jpg";
>
> print http_file_exists($url);

The error it returns is:

> Warning: fopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /srv/http/webshop3/image_scraper/test.php on line 6 Warning: fopen(http://www.minhemmelighed.dk/Graphics/Products/55.jpg): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /srv/http/webshop3/image_scraper/test.php on line 6

What can I do about this? I have rebooted the server several times.

For the record:

I can access the website in question through a browser

I am running LAMP on Arch Linux

Comment: Does DNS work on the server too? How did you test that you coan access the website in question?

Comment: DNS should work, I think? How can I test that? :) I accessed the website in my browser without problems

Comment: See my answer for a way to test DNS. Don't forget to test it *on the server as the php user*. (Oh, and try not to claim it works if you didn't actually test it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rebooting a UNIX server is extremely unlikely to fix a problem. It looks like you need to check your nameserver configuration on the server. On the console of the web server (logged in as the php user, probably `apache` or `www-data`), test

```
dig www.minhemmelighed.dk
```

If this outputs an error message, check your `/etc/resolv.conf`. Comment out all lines and add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # Google's public DNS server
```

If that solves the problem, contact the administrator of the original nameserver (or just use Google's `8.8.8.8`). If it doesn't, check your connectivity and firewalls.

Comment: Thanks :) But it didn't fix the problem :S I am afraid that it's an Apache Server error :(

Comment: @Eax At what step did you fail? I.e. did the `dig` work? The problem is almost certainly completely unrelated to the HTTP server, Apache or otherwise.

Comment: Sorry :) Dig didn't fail, I can also visit minhemmelighed.dk in my browser without a problem :)

Comment: @Eax If `dig` succeeds on the *server* as the *php user* (`su apache` or `su www-data`), can you post a link to the output of `strace php -r 'file_get_contents("http://www.minhemmelighed.dk/Graphics/Products/55.jpg");'` at http://pastebin.com or so?

Comment: Neither of those users exist :S

Comment: @Eax Use `ps -A u | grep apache` to find out the user name (in the first column).

Comment: @Eax The paste is executed as the user `eax`. Is that the user php's running as? And it shows DNS and actual HTTP download working, so it's obviously not the problematic configuration.

Comment: That is what 
ps -A u | grep apache

returns yes, (so yes, it is executed as eax)

Comment: Many thanks. This has been bugging me for a couple of hours and the google DNS fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you running a very locked down distro like CentOS it is probably a security feature of SELinux as I discovered on my systems.

At the command prompt type:

**getsebool -a | grep httpd**

and look for

**httpd_verify_dns --> off**

if this is the case you will need to set it On with the following command

**setsebool httpd_verify_dns=1**

or permanently with:

**setsebool -P httpd_verify_dns=1**

remember to restart httpd with:

**service httpd restart**
after every change

I hope that helps

Mark