# PHP fopen(): getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, fopen

So I'm trying to read from a remote file (which used to work) and it stopped working after transferring servers. The code looks like this:

```
$import_handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/path/", "r");
```

This is the error I'm getting (from error_get_last()):

```
fopen(http://www.example.com/path/): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I can confirm that example.com/path is working. What's the cause of the error and what am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064372/file-get-contents-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-servi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897506/fopen-fails-with-getaddrinfo-failed)? Have you considered using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)? (will likely have the same issue, but may be better-suited to what you're trying to do)

Comment: Yes, I stumbled across them - the thing is, it used to work before and only the remote site changed servers, not the one I'm running the script off from. I use fopen() since I need to do fgets() as the remote script being opened is a generated CSV file. And I don't have access to Apache on both servers, only FTP.

Comment: Update: file_get_contents() returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, it was mainly because my php.ini settings was

`allow_url_fopen=Off` 
changing that to 
`allow_url_fopen=On`
Solved the issue, remember to restart your Apache Server after changing it.

Answer (score -2):

I just found the solution!

I changed

`$import_handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/path/", "r");`

to

```
$import_handle = fopen("path/", "r");
```